# Trying to sharpen an image while using an edge detection function

Tags: python

```
from images import Image
def main():
    image=Image("smokey.gif")
    amount=40
    sharp=20
    newimage=detectedges(image,amount,sharp)
    newimage.draw()


def detectedges(image,amount,sharp):
    def average(triple):
        (r,g,b)=triple
        return(r+g+b)
    blackPixel=(0,0,0)
    whitePixel=(255,255,255)
    new=image.clone()
    for y in range(image.getHeight()-1):
        for x in range(1,image.getWidth()):
            oldPixel=image.getPixel(x,y)
            leftPixel=image.getPixel(x-1,y)
            bottomPixel=image.getPixel(x,y+1)
            oldLum=average(oldPixel)
            leftLum=average(leftPixel)
            bottomLum=average(bottomPixel)
            if abs(oldLum-leftLum)>amount or\
               abs(oldLum-bottomLum)>amount:
                new.setPixel(x,y)-(sharp)
    return new
main()
```

The problem I am having is that when I try to subtract the pixel color by sharp to make the pixel darker it instead gives me these error messages which gives me the error message, Image.setPixel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'

I've tried switching up how I wrote the code but ended up getting error messages, what I expected to happen from this was that the images colors would get darker if they were above the amount. Resulted in the error message, Image.setPixel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'

Comment: Why don't you pass the missing argument to setPixel?

Comment: Im kind of new im not too sure how to pass it

Comment: Just write another value after `setPixel(x, y, ` and before `)`.